# example of container-wide profiling with perf

Tags: record, perf, cgroups

Can anybody give an example of container-wide profiling with perf?

perf manual has following explanation:
       -G name,..., --cgroup name,...
           monitor only in the container (cgroup) called "name". This option is available only in per-cpu mode. The cgroup filesystem must be mounted.
           All threads belonging to container "name" are monitored when they run on the monitored CPUs. Multiple cgroups can be provided. Each cgroup is
           applied to the corresponding event, i.e., first cgroup to first event, second cgroup to second event and so on. It is possible to provide an
           empty cgroup (monitor all the time) using, e.g., -G foo,,bar. Cgroups must have corresponding events, i.e., they always refer to events
           defined earlier on the command line.

But how to get the cgroup name? If my program wants to profile the entire container it resides in, how to get its host cgroup's name that perf recognize?

Any example perf commands would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`perf` uses cgroups in the `perf_event` hierarchy to determine which processes to track. Docker creates all of the `perf_event` cgroups inside a cgroup called `docker`, and the containers are identified by their full container ID hash. You can get this via `docker ps --no-trunc` on the host, or `grep perf /proc/self/cgroup | cut -d : -f 3` inside the container.

The argument to `perf` is then `--cgroup=docker/container_id`